# How to use dictionery for creating a list through input

Tags: python

I am writing a program, which is supposed to collect data on the applicants for the study specialist affair and evaluate their eligibility for a tuition-waiver. Could you help to find out why it doesn't work?
P.S. I edited my code today according to the comments and the first function works without any problem. Now I need to understand how to apply dict in the second function. Any help is appreciated, I never used it before.

```
def ask_questions():
    list_of_applicants = []
    count = 0
    num_applicants = int(input("no. of applicants: "))
    
    while num_applicants > count:
        try:
            name = input("name: ")
            gender = input("gender: ")
            income = int(input("income: "))
            count+=1
        except:
            print("Enter a valid data")
            
        dict = {'name': name, 'gender': gender, 'income': income}
        print(dict)
        list_of_applicants.append(dict)
    return list_of_applicants

def make_decision (applicant_list, max_income=1000):

    for applicant in applicant_list: # applicant = {'name': name, 'gender': gender, 'income': income}

        if applicant["income"] > max_income and applicant["gender"] == "male":
            print("The applicant", applicant['name'], "is not eligible for tution-waiver")
        elif applicant["income"] > max_income and applicant["gender"] == "female": 
            print("The applicant", applicant['name'], "is not eligible for tution-waiver but eligible for the scholarship Women in IT")
        else:
            print("The applicant", applicant['name'], "is eligible for tution-waiver")
            
ask_questions()
```

Currently output is like that:

```
no. of applicants: 2
name: Albina
gender: female
income: 900
{'name': 'Albina', 'gender': 'female', 'income': 900}
name: Svetlana
gender: female
income: 900
{'name': 'Svetlana', 'gender': 'female', 'income': 900}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Альбина\Desktop\study\Homework\project.py", line 31, in <module>
    make_decision(applicant_list, max_income=1000)
NameError: name 'applicant_list' is not defined
```

Comment: Please let us know what the expected output is, and what the current output is.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of errors with your code. A few being:

- `max_income` is not defined in the `make_decision` function. Pass this as a parameter or initialize.
- Same goes for `name`, `income` and `gender`.

The sample code you made doesn't call these functions either. You need to at least call them using `ask_questions()` in your base code. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You defined the function, but you didn't call it.

You need to add `ask_questions()` to the end of your code, and then a similar one to run the second function.

If you have any questions, feel free to comment!

Comment: Thank you! I felt that I need to call ask_questions but I didn't know the syntax. I am only learning programming for a month. Where to add it in the second function?

Comment: You should do something like ```make_decision(ask_questions(), <max income variable>)``` at the end of your code, to make ask_questions return its list to make_decision.